# Missing Encryption Key when migrating Reporting Services from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016, ssrs

Owing to a ransomware attack on our production server Reporting Services went down. This server was installed few years ago and its been in production for long. We have quite a few reports on this server.

It was decided we build a new server and migrate the ReportServer Database. Unfortunately we don't have the Encryption Key. Because the service is down I can't even take the back up now, its too late.

I tried backing up the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB databases and then restoring those to the new servers. Restore went well, I even changed the database from the reporting services configuration manager.

But, When I tried to go to the web portal URL, It shows the error , The report server isn't configured properly. Check the report server trace log for details. I found out that logs shows the scale out deployment errors. I believe since I don't have the encryption key file and password I am receiving this error.

What can I do to get reporting services up and running...?

What should be my approach..? Can I restore the encryption key some how or create a new one with rskeymgmt..? If not then can I delete it (if it is possible) and try to reconfigure all the reports again..? (There are about 350 different reports on this server).

Please help.

Comment: May I know what did you do to restore the encryption key if you did?

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately we don't have the Encryption Key.

This is the problem, and you already know what I'm going to say next. I hope your 350 reports were in a source control system.

Comment: Thanks Randolph West for the reply. Is there a way to delete the encryption key while the reporting services is not running? I will re-configure the connection strings and subscriptions and whatever else is required, if I can get atleast unencrypted part of my reports.

Comment: I don't think you understand. You will have to start over from scratch.

Comment: I was just hoping to find the solution in this desperate times. I really appreciate your time and efforts to help me.